# How can I make a Bullet Tracer in BGE?

Tags: game-engine

I was watching a thing on this [MMoG](http://www.blendernation.com/2015/03/31/dust-of-adventure-multiplayer-online-game-bge/) that some German kids made and noticed they had really nice shooting actions. every time one of them shot, a bright white line would appear. How would I recreate this for my game? I don't want to use thousands of textured planes cause my machine isn't that great and I  don't want to blow it up: happened before.

**NOTE:** I don't really know if that effect is called a tracer, so if someone knows the real name, I'd be happy!

Comment: The muzzle flash? or the bullet mesh? Does it move?

Comment: if it is a simple line try `render.drawLine(muzzle, bullet, white)`

Comment: If the bullet fires straight, why couldn't you just have the gun also shot one partly transparent shadeless plane with a muzzle flash texture that lasts a frame or two?

Comment: Just found an awesome way to do it! answer coming soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by having your gun, in addition to firing your bullet, also fire a no-colision plane. this plane scales from 0 to 100 in 100 frames. the gun also shoots a bullet that travels one frame every logic tick. when the animation of your laser is running at one frame for every logic tick, the end result will be a no-colision plane filling the space between the gun and the bullet before impact. In the demo below, I have the bullet invisible. All you can see is the scaling plane.

[image]

To make your plane scale to get it elongating at a rate of one Blender unit per Logic Tick, use this logic setup.

[image]

You need to start with a plane, and move the origin to one edge. then move the edge opposite the origin in to make it One blender unit by Two blender units.

[image]

Then set the timeline to frame 100, and in object mode press <kbd>S</kbd> to start the scale, press <kbd>X</kbd> to constrain the scale along the X axis. Press <kbd>100</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> this will set the scale so that the demotions will be 100 blender units by 2 blender units. press <kbd>I</kbd> to set a keyframe, and select **Scale**

[image]

this will set a keyframe with the scale on frame 100.

Now do the same thing at frame 0, only this time we need to set the scale along the X axis to 0.

Set the timeline to frame 0, press <kbd>S</kbd> to start the scale, press <kbd>X</kbd> to constrain the scale along the X axis. Press <kbd>0</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> this will set the scale so that the demotions will be 0 blender units by 2 blender units. press <kbd>I</kbd> to set a keyframe, and select **Scale**

Now we have the scale animated from frame 0 to frame 100.

However, if we move the timeline, we can see that the animation is not quite right.

[image]

We can fix this by going into the graph editor and changing the curve type to *linear*

[image]

Now when we test it, we can see that every frame makes the plane scal one blender unit longer.

[image]

Comment: Awesome possum... how'd you do it in the santa game?

Comment: That was fairly simple,When you fired the gun, it shot a stream of fast moving, invisible bullets while it randomly changed the visibility for a few no-colision planes that were always pointing away from the gun in random directions.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a simple logic brick setup:

Always sensor on TRUE pulse(*3 dots on top* button). You could tweak it to set how much smoke is generated. Then, in another layer, make a plane, you can either: in the materials, find *face orientation*, set it to *halo*, and change rotation until you get it right. You can also duplicate the plane and rotate it 90 degrees on the Z axis, to give it a 3D look. Than give it a smoke texture.(Use CG Textures to find one). Back to your bullet: make an *edit object* actuator, *add object*, (smoke object) and connect it to your always sensor.  And that is it. You can give the smoke a fading animation, a delay with an *edit object* actuator, set to *end object*. But that is up yo you!