# Add a line between two objects?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I have empty1, the empty **that fires the bullet(s),** and empty2, the empty **that is always at the center of the screen.** *If you are confused about empty2's function, look at [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13790/how-do-i-make-a-weapon-shoot-at-the-center-of-the-screen) question.* On command, I need a line, which is our bullet, to be added. I obviously can't just add a line that starts at empty1 and is endless as that causes *many* issues. When the command to shoot a bullet is sent, *I need a line to be created, starting from **empty1,** and I need to it to continue towards **empty2.*** In other words, I need a line to be between two objects (for my case, empties). What is the best way to achieve this? Thanks!

EDIT: I prefer that the "line" is an object as I'll be planning to change its color, thickness, etc.

Comment: see if this what you need http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28535/how-can-i-make-a-bullet-tracer-in-bge

Comment: @Chebhou I already looked at that earlier, thanks though. This question is quite different, not so much though.

Comment: you need a line straight from one point to another ? you can use `render.drawline()`

Comment: @Chebhou Problem is, I don't know how to use python. I am planning to, but since I've made it so far in this and the remaining parts don't need much python, I've planned to learn later.

Comment: OK it's your call

Comment: @Chebhou If you know how to do this with python that is great. I am not saying I don't want python. Whatever anyone makes, if it works, no one can tell them they are wrong.

Comment: so does the line need to be visible like "drawline" or can you have two rays operating in different directions of each other saying "if both rays but not one ray"

Comment: sorry, that's not very clear. if you have one ray shooting -y from empty 1 and another ray shooting y from empty two, then the area where they both exist is the area between them, so that means you essentially get an area that grows or shrinks based on the distance between the empties and can be sensed by "if both rays".

Comment: @Vince Scalia What i'm hearing is that you think I want **2 rays.** I am looking for one ray that updates all the time, and is basically between two points. Yes, it can move around.

Comment: Everyone that has already made a comment; I am sorry about this: I changed the question a little. By "ray," I meant "line." Hope this doesn't cause many issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I added these to clarify what I do

[image]
You could select one empty, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> --> Cursor to selected!
[image]

Add a curve (since you can modify it's thickness), press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter 'edit mode', select one vertex, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> --> Selection to cursor. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to exit 'edit mode'
[image]

Select the other empty, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> --> Cursor to selected. Then select the curve, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter 'edit mode'
[image]
select the other vertex, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> --> selection to cursor
[image]

result:
[image]

Comment: And does the line show in-game? Does the line always change position when the empties are changing?